# Cannot convert value of type int into Expected argument type 'CGfloat'

Tags: swift, int

I'm trying to create subviews in my app programmatically, basically I'm a beginner in swift, while I trying to create 9 subview. I got an error "Cannot convert value of type 'int' into Expected argument type 'CGfloat'"
CGFloat values are A & B

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class Subview: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var view1 : UIView = UIView() {
        didSet {
            var A:CGFloat = 0
            var B:CGFloat = 0
            for A in 1...3 {
                for B in 1...3 {
                    view1.frame = CGRectMake(A,B, 100, 100)
                    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                    self.addSubview(view1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you use Swift initializers, i.e. `CGRect(x:y:width:height:)` instead of `CGRectMake()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overloaded `A` and `B` variables in cycles with same name but `Int` type variables (read more about `for in` cycle). You don't need to declare variables before use them as elements in `for in`, they are implicitly created in local cycle scope with type of elements of your collection (again, `Int` in your case). `CGRectMake(_:_:_:_:)` expect from you `CGFloat`'s; and as @Martin R pointed you better use `CGRect(x:y:width:height:)`. This code will solve conversion type problem:

```
didSet {
    for A in 1...3 {
        for B in 1...3 {
            view1.frame = CGRect(x: A, y: B, width: 100, height: 100)
            view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            self.addSubview(view1)
        }
    }
}
```

But it have other, logic problems. Instance of `UIView` (view1) can be added only in one view hierarchy at same time. So, in fact, all code in your `didSet` will have just same result as this code:

```
didSet {
    view1.frame = CGRect(x: 3, y: 3, width: 100, height: 100)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.addSubview(view1)
}
```

Note also, that `didSet` observer not invoked on initialization step, so if you will not reassign `view1` property this code will never be executed.

Comment: Better use `CGRect(x: A, y: B, width: 100, height: 100)`, as `CGRectMake`  is removed in Swift 3 (and it saves you the type conversion).

Answer (score 0):

@NDoc answer will help you but you need to know how for in works
you don't have to declare A and B, just use

```
for A in 0...3 {
for B in 0...3 {
```

it will increase by itself